# php image loses its quality after resize

Tags: php, image

I have a problem of image quality after a resize. Could you help me to find a solution to my problem?

This is a page where an image has been resized
goo.gl/5mYxxb , 460*275 and this the code that I am using to resize :

```
$newwidth = 460;
$newheight = 275;
$newwidth1 = 146;
$newheight2 = 88;
$temp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

$black2 = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp,0,0,0,65);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
imagecopyresampled($temp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
Imagettftext($temp, 16, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black2, $font , "text");
imagejpeg($temp, $path,95);
imagedestroy($temp);
$temp2 = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight2);
imagecopyresampled($temp2, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth1, $newheight2, $width, $height);
Imagettftext($temp2, 8, 0, $start_x2, $start_y2, $black2, $font , "text");
imagejpeg($temp2,$pathFile ,90);
imagedestroy($temp2);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: what is the original size of the image?

Comment: original size is 960 * 1600

Comment: `imagejpeg($temp, $path,95);` here you overwrite original image

Comment: so should i replace $temp by $src ?